# Difficulty in programming using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How to write program for equation ∑t*phase(i)

```
a = 3.86;    
a1 = (a/2) * [sqrt(3), -1, 0];
a2 = (a/2) * [sqrt(3), 1, 0];
coordinates = [4.45714 0 0; %B
               2.22857 0 0.46152]; %A
R1 = coordinates(2, :)-coordinates(1,:);
R2 = R1 + a1;
R3 = R1 + a2;
R = [R1' R2' R3'];
t=-2.5;

phase(i) = exp(1i*dot(k(:,index),R(:,i));
(i=1:3)
```

Comment: Please, use code formatting (button with "{}").

Comment: `answer = sum(t*phase);`

Comment: "Difficulty in programming using MATLAB" is **NOT** a question. Please,try to use a title that describes your problem more specifically.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provide does not work as it is currently written. Index is not defined for example, and the brackets are mismatched.

However going from the title and question you would simply be looking for something like this:

```
for p =1:3
     phase(p) = % Something here
end

sum(t*phase)
```

As was already mentioned by @ray in the comments.

---

Something to note

You use `i` as a loop variable and then use 1i (which is the square root of minus 1). This is something you do NOT want to have in any code as it is very confusing.